# Is it possible to have a spinner and a list view on the same page?

Tags: android, listview

I want to have a spinner at the top of page, and then generate a list view below the spinner according to what the user has selected from the spinner, does anyone know a good tutorial for this or have some code lying around that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example using an ArrayAdapter over a string array for populating the spinner:

```
// Create string array adapter to populate spinner
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_string_array,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// Set the spinners content adapter and add onSelect listener
Spinner spinnerExample = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.id_to_spinner);
spinnerExample.setAdapter(adapter);
spinnerExample.setOnItemSelectedListener(listerner);

// Get a reference to the ListView that will be used in the listener
listViewToPopulate = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.id_to_listview);
```

And the associated OnClickListener to handle list population:

```
OnItemSelectedListener listerner = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView,
            View paramView, int paramInt, long paramLong) {
        String selection = (String)paramAdapterView.getItemAtPosition(paramInt);
        // Populate list based on selection
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView) {
        // do nothing
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Create a layout containing spinner and listview. In the listactivtiy, use setContentView to create a view based on the layout. Get a handle on the spinner (findViewById) and do whatever you need to do with it. Based on the spinner selection - set the array or cursor for your listview adapter. That should be enough.