# Is it possible to have a spinner and a list view on the same view?

Tags: android, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have a spinner and a list view on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418533/is-it-possible-to-have-a-spinner-and-a-list-view-on-the-same-page)

I want to have a spinner at the top of view, and then generate a list view below the spinner according to what the user has selected from the spinner, does anyone know a good tutorial for this or have some code lying around that might help?

I have had success using a ListView by extending ListActivity, but in this case I want to have things other than the ListView in the view, so I am not sure what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can create layout for your activity, for example (layout_with_spinner):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:id="@+id/layout1">
    <LinearLayout   
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some text"/>
        <Spinner 
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"                                  
            android:id="@+id/spinner1" />                         

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list_view" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>         
</LinearLayout>
```

and then you can create class extended from Activity

```
public class YourCoolActivity extends Activity
{
    private Spinner mSpinner;
    private ListView mList;             
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_with_spinner);
            mSpinner= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view); 
            //here create some adapter. 
            mSpinner.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
            //set listener on select
            mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()     
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id)
        {                           
                         //here you can populate list with data
                         //create new list adapter depended on  (YourObjectModel)mSpinner.getSelectedItem()
                        // or pos
                         mList.setAdapter(newListAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {           
        }           
    }); 

    }
}
```

Maybe it helps to start. You can look at this 
[sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) to look at some sample about spinners

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect to get me started.